# How to pass data between Meteor Template Helpers?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

Meteor Newbie here!

I have a page where all the open orders are displayed. The order details are stored in a collection. A Template helper will return the order details.

```
Template.delivery.helpers({
  openOrders: function(){
   return Orders.find({status: "open"});
  }
});
```

The template look some what like this.

```
{{#if openOrders}}
  {{#each openOrders}}
     Date: {{createdAt}}
     Total items: {{items.length}}
     Location: {{location}} //It prints the location _id
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

The **Order** Collection only have the _id of the location. The Location details are stored in a Collection named **Locations**.

I want to display the location name (which is stored in the Location collection) instead of the _id.

I created a Template helper which returns the Location details, but how can I link these to helpers so that the `Location name` is displayed instead of `Location _id`?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `mongodb` in a relational database fashion, you need to install `publish-composite` package to make sure all the necessary data are subscribed.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `each`, it will set the `this` to the current thing that is being iterated over. This will allow you to use `this` in your helper to perform lookups. So in this case, if you're using a helper to get the orders:

```
orders: function () {
  return Orders.find({ status: "orders" });
}
```

Then when you iterate over it with `{{#each}}`, `this` is set to the current order, meaning your location helper with look like this:

```
location: function () {
  return Locations.findOne(this.locationId);
}
```

Putting it all together in the template it would be like:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  {{#each orders}}
    <h1 class="title">Order #{{_id}}</h1>
    {{#with location}}
      <div class="location">
        <span>Latitude: {{ latitude }}</span>
      </div>
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Keep in mind: **this will only work if you also publish your locations**.